# Increase the Size of animating box on Hover but It should not go outside of visible display during transition on edge

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, css-transitions

I am creating a box which animates, and moves and when i hover on it, it increases the size of the box. But when I hover on the box on the Edge of the display the increasing size of the box so it goes outside of visible display, but i want it to be inside of the visible display. CSS or JS both can work. My code is below.

```
body{
     overflow-x: hidden;
  }

#box1{

  width: 5cm;
  height: 4cm;

  position: relative;
  background-color: green;

  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

}

```
@keyframes anim{

     0%{
         top: 0px;
         left: 0px; } 
    
     40%{
         top: 300px;
         left: 500px; }
 
     75%{
         top: 500px; 
         left: 10px;  }
    
     100%{
         top: 0;
         left: 0; }
   }

            
 #box1:hover{

      animation-play-state: paused;
      height: 300px; /* you can change it acc to you */
      width:300px;  /* you can change it acc to you */
    }
}
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vugonulidi/edit?html,css,output) link is here for website

Comment: if you don't know the complete solution but if you have any idea regarding this question then please feel free to tell here casually.

Comment: if you are not getting the question then also ask to explain